# PEP8-compliant way to line-wrap a chain of ['item']['item'] lookups

Tags: python, pep8

**E501: line too long (88 > 79 characters)**

```
if true:
    if true:
        if true:
            record = self.content['data']['country_name']['city_name']['postal_address']
```

My failed attempt:

```
if true:
    if true:
        if true:
            record = self.content['data']['country_name'] \
                                 ['city_name']['postal_address']
```

This is giving an error: **E211 whitespace before '['  line: 4, column: 58**

I'm using: [http://pep8online.com](http://pep8online.com/)

Comment: BTW, the title edit is an attempt to make that title more self-contained -- places where a title uses "this" to refer to question content, such that someone needs to click through to know what "this" is before they can tell if they have an answer (or if they have the same problem), is a bit like clickbait.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, sounds better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways, one possibility (that I would prefer) is just adding intermediate variables (with some meaningful names).

```
if True:
    if True:
        if True:
            data = self.content['data']
            record = data['country_name']['city_name']['postal_address']
```

Also, three nested `if`s are probably a good candidate for some refactoring, maybe with some auxiliary functions, that would also reduce the line length.

Yet another alternative: use parentheses (recommended by PEP8 over the backslash too)

```
        record = (
            self.content
            ['data']
            ['country_name']
            ['city_name']
            ['postal_address']
        )
```

Comment: Hey Jose! I liked the second option... very neat! thanks

Comment: My pleasure ! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, but if you just want something that makes the automated style checker happy...

```
if true:
    if true:
        if true:
            record = self.content['data']['country_name'
                                          ]['city_name']['postal_address']
```

Comment: works perfectly! However, I agree it looks terrible :-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, consider if two `if` clauses can be merged with the `and` operator.

But, assuming each `if` clause will have a different condition, it may be placed inside a method where you may add one or several guard clauses that will exit early:

```
def get_content(content):
    if not True:
        return

    if not True:
        return

    if not True:
        return

    return content['data']['country_name']['city_name']['postal_address']


record = get_content(content)
```

You may also consider to create intermediate variables, that may help making it both more readable and shorter.

Comment: This reminds me very much of the excellent advice given in the essay [Code: Align The Happy Path To The Left Edge](https://medium.com/@matryer/line-of-sight-in-code-186dd7cdea88).

Comment: I have seen student grade code that nested 5 to 10 levels of `if` clauses. It was an amazing piece of C code, but then it was found it had a bug, and turns out it as very difficult to debug. Also, I have been reading a lot of `if A != B" with other `if clauses` inside, sometimes deeply nested. But since I first heard about the term "guard clause", it became a lot easier to explain other people why it is frequently a good idea to exit early and recover a few indentation levels and code clarity.